# XSLT 2.0 how to test for position() in tokenize() on output

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0 I have a parameter than comes in as a delimited string of document names like:
`ms609_0080.xml~ms609_0176.xml~ms609_0210.xml~ms609_0418.xml`

I `tokenize()` this string and cycle through it with `xsl:for-each` to pass each document to a `key`. The results from the key I then assemble into a comma-delimited string to output to screen.

```
<xsl:variable name="list_of_corresp_events">
   <xsl:variable name ="tokenparam" select="tokenize($paramCorrespdocs,'~')"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$tokenparam">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".[position() != last()]">
               <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($paramSaxondatapath, .))/(key('correspkey',$correspid))/@xml:id"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(document(concat($paramSaxondatapath, .))/(key('correspkey',$correspid))/@xml:id, ', ')"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Everything works fine except that when I output the variable  `$list_of_corresp_events` it looks like the following, with an unexpected trailing comma:

`ms609-0080-2, ms609-0176-1, ms609-0210-1, ms609-0418-1,`

Ordinarily the last comma should not appear based on `test=".[position() != last()]"` ?  Possibly positions don't work for tokenized data? I didn't see a way to apply `string-join()` to this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:when test=".[position() != last()]">
```

to

```
<xsl:when test="position() != last()">
```

Then it should all work as desired.

Comment: By way of explanation, "." is a single item, that is, a sequence of length one, and in a sequence of length 1, `position()` and `last()` will always be 1, therefore `position() != last()` will always be false, therefore `.[position() != last()]` will always be an empty sequence, therefore the test will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on the solution from @zx485, try

```
<xsl:for-each select="$tokenparam">
   <xsl:if test="position()!=1">, </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($paramSaxondatapath, .))/(key('correspkey',$correspid))/@xml:id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Two things here:

(a) you don't need to repeat the same code in both conditional branches

(b) it's more efficient to output the comma separator before every item except the first, rather than after every item except the last. That's because evaluating `last()` involves an expensive look-ahead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can simplify this to

```
<xsl:variable name="list_of_corresp_events">
   <xsl:value-of select="for $t in tokenize($paramCorrespdocs,'~') document(concat($paramSaxondatapath, $))/(key('correspkey',$correspid))/@xml:id" separator=", "/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or with `string-join`

```
<xsl:variable name="list_of_corresp_events" select="string-join(for $t in tokenize($paramCorrespdocs,'~') document(concat($paramSaxondatapath, $))/(key('correspkey',$correspid))/@xml:id, ', ')"/>
```